# Visual Studio 2010 crashes at startup, even in safe mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

I have Visual Studio 2010 Premium in a virtual machine (VM) and all was working fine until today, when I uninstalled Office 2010 Trial, installed Office 2010 Professional, and created a snapshot of my VM.

Now when I open Visual Studio, the interface appears for one or two seconds and disappears. The problem comes when I open a solution (.sln) file (it crashes after loading the solution) or when I just open Visual Studio 2010 (even in Safe Mode).

How do I fix this?

```
Here is the log:

    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>
  <entry>
    <record>1</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:20.894</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 version: 10.0.30319.1</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:21.234</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Running in User Groups: Administrators Users</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>3</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:21.304</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Available Drive Space: C:\ drive has 11464269824 bytes</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>4</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:21.334</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Internet Explorer Version: 8.0.6001.19120</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>5</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:21.725</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>.NET Framework Version: 4.0.31106.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>6</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:21.735</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>MSXML Version: 6.20.1103.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>7</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:21.915</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Creating PkgDefCacheNonVolatile</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>8</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.086</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Double-checking master pkgdef file</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>9</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.146</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefManagement initialized</description>
  </entry>
   <entry>
    <record>12</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.296</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefSearchPath</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>

  <entry>
    <record>15</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.456</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Searching for PkgDefs from search path</description>
    <path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>16</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.486</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>User extensions enabled by setting</description>
    <path>HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ExtensionManager\EnableAdminExtensions</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>17</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.536</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Missing folder or file during PkgDef scan</description>
    <hr>80030002</hr>
    <path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>18</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.556</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Discovered 14 PkgDef files</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>20</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.596</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Current pkgdef cache timestamp is valid</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>21</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.616</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Checking age of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE vs PkgDef cache</description>
    <path>Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>22</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.837</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Newest node in merge source</description>
    <path>UITestExtensionPackages</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>23</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.847</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef configuration cache is OK</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>24</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.857</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDefManagement startup complete</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>25</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.857</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>AppId setting up registry detouring</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>26</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:22.867</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Adding detour rule 1: from HKLM</description>
    <path>Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0</path>
  </entry>     
  <entry>
    <record>31</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:23.227</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>32</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:23.698</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>33</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:23.718</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Environment Package Window Management]</description>
    <guid>{5E56B3DB-7964-4588-8D49-D3523AB7BDB9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>34</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:23.888</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>35</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:23.908</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Shell Common UI Package]</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>36</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:23.918</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Shell Common UI Package]</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>37</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.349</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>38</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.359</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function LoadDTETypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>39</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.369</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function LoadDTETypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>40</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.369</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>41</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.379</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>42</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.379</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{18BEB7F2-CA98-11D1-B6E7-00A0C90F2744}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>43</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.399</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>44</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.399</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>45</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.409</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>46</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.419</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>47</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.419</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{53544C4D-E3F8-4AA0-8195-8A8D16019423}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>48</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.419</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Source Control Integration Package]</description>
    <guid>{53544C4D-E3F8-4AA0-8195-8A8D16019423}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>49</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.429</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{D79B7E0A-F994-4D4D-8FAE-CAE147279E21}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>50</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.429</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [team foundation server provider stub package]</description>
    <guid>{D79B7E0A-F994-4D4D-8FAE-CAE147279E21}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>51</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.429</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [team foundation server provider stub package]</description>
    <guid>{D79B7E0A-F994-4D4D-8FAE-CAE147279E21}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>52</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.429</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Source Control Integration Package]</description>
    <guid>{53544C4D-E3F8-4AA0-8195-8A8D16019423}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>53</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.479</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{A9405AE6-9AC6-4F0E-A03F-7AFE45F6FCB7}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>54</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.489</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.QualityToolsPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TestCaseManagement, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{A9405AE6-9AC6-4F0E-A03F-7AFE45F6FCB7}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>55</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.679</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.QualityToolsPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TestCaseManagement, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{A9405AE6-9AC6-4F0E-A03F-7AFE45F6FCB7}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>56</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.809</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>57</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.819</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Tips.TuipPackage.TuipPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.TuipPackage, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>58</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.870</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>59</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.940</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual C# Project System]</description>
    <guid>{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>60</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:24.950</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>61</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.300</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Common IDE Package]</description>
    <guid>{6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>62</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.320</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Common IDE Package]</description>
    <guid>{6E87CFAD-6C05-4ADF-9CD7-3B7943875B7C}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>63</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.330</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</guid>
    <path>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\*\csprojui.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>64</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.340</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual C# Project System]</description>
    <guid>{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>65</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.340</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{164B10B9-B200-11D0-8C61-00A0C91E29D5}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>66</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.350</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Basic Project System]</description>
    <guid>{164B10B9-B200-11D0-8C61-00A0C91E29D5}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>67</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.350</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{164B10B9-B200-11D0-8C61-00A0C91E29D5}</guid>
    <path>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VB\Bin\*\msvbprjui.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>68</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.360</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Basic Project System]</description>
    <guid>{164B10B9-B200-11D0-8C61-00A0C91E29D5}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>69</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.360</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Tips.TuipPackage.TuipPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.TuipPackage, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{52CBD135-1F97-2580-011F-C7CD052E44DE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>70</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.390</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{6077292C-6751-4483-8425-9026BC0187B6}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>71</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.390</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Unknown]</description>
    <guid>{6077292C-6751-4483-8425-9026BC0187B6}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>72</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.410</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Unknown]</description>
    <guid>{6077292C-6751-4483-8425-9026BC0187B6}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>73</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.591</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{7494682B-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>74</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.591</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Windows Forms Designer Package]</description>
    <guid>{7494682B-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>75</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.601</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Windows Forms Designer Package]</description>
    <guid>{7494682B-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>76</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.701</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{DA9FB551-C724-11D0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>77</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.711</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Environment Package]</description>
    <guid>{DA9FB551-C724-11D0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>78</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:25.711</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Environment Package]</description>
    <guid>{DA9FB551-C724-11D0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>79</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.652</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>80</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.652</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Logging Package]</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>81</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.662</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
    <path>c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE*\VsLogUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>82</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.672</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Logging Package]</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>83</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.672</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>84</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.682</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio Environment Menu Package]</description>
    <guid>{715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>85</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.682</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Environment Menu Package]</description>
    <guid>{715F10EB-9E99-11D2-BFC2-00C04F990235}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>86</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.682</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{0E13FC54-9231-410B-8B74-95689CD32627}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>87</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.692</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Start Page]</description>
    <guid>{0E13FC54-9231-410B-8B74-95689CD32627}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>88</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.692</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Start Page]</description>
    <guid>{0E13FC54-9231-410B-8B74-95689CD32627}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>89</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.712</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>90</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.722</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [MRU Data Source]</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>91</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.722</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [MRU Data Source]</description>
    <guid>{8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>92</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.832</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>ProductID: </description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>93</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:26.912</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Data Access Version: 2.81.1132.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>94</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:27.343</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Application Name: Microsoft Visual Studio</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>95</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:27.343</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SKU Edition: Premium</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>96</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:27.844</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Shutting down pkgdef registry</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>97</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:27.874</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Released pkgdef cache usage tracker</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>98</record>
    <time>2011/10/03 13:41:27.914</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef registry shutdown complete</description>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 9):

If Roman's suggestion does not pan out, I would reset the entire VS installation.  You can do this as follows from the VS command prompt:

```
devenv.exe /resetsettings
devenv.exe /setup
```

This should put VS back to it original installed state.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. Note too that you must run `devenv /setup` as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem caused by changing one of my project's property pages during compilation. The following steps solved this issue:

1. Open Visual Studio 2008.
2. Open some project you have or create new empty project.
3. Modify the debugger command to point to the visual studio 2010 devenv.exe.
4. Launch the debugger and the Visual Studio 2010 will run.
5. Press File -> Exit from the Visual Studio 2010 menu, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions as for working around the problem without knowing the specific cause of the crash:

- Disable Visual Studio Add-Ins
- Delete solution/project temporary files (such as .SDF, intermediate files, etc.)

Re-open the solution file in a restarted Visual Studio to give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine:
logged in as another user (administrator) 
launched visual studio 10 ultimate.

It worked.
Came BACK as my normal user - all was well.

- I did a remote desktop connection to the same machine as a different user
- I did a /resetsettings before attempting the other user